# Pyhon. Cannot successfully provide password to CMD standard input 7-zip decryption command

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I am using the 7za.exe command line version of 7 zip for my compression/encryption and decompression/decryption needs. 
For improved security, I am not executing the command in CMD with the password. Rather, I am passing in the password using subprocess and passing it in to the CMD's standard input.

Here is my execute function which is being used to run system commands with input.

```html
    def execute(self, cmd : typing.List[str], input: typing.Optional[bytes] = None, verbose=False, debug=False, normal_priority=False):
        if verbose:
            print(cmd)
        creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
        if normal_priority:
            creationflags |= subprocess.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
        else:
            creationflags |= subprocess.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS

        if debug:
            process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,creationflags=creationflags)
        else:
            process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=creationflags)
        if input:
            process.stdin.write(input)
            process.stdin.flush()
        returncode = process.wait()
        if returncode:
            raise OSError(returncode)
```

Here is my decompression/Decryption function

```html
    def sevenZipDecompressDecryptFileFolder(self, file, destinationPath=None, password=None):
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(file):
                self.CELogger.error(f"The file ({file}) does not exist for encryption")
                return False

            theFilepath = pathlib.Path(file)
            theFilesuffix = theFilepath.suffix
            theFilename = theFilepath.stem

            if theFilesuffix != '.7z':
                self.CELogger.error(f"The file ({file}) does not have the .7z extension")
                return False
            if destinationPath is None:
                parentFolders = str(theFilepath.parent)
                decryptedFilepath = os.path.join(parentFolders)
            else:
                if not os.path.exists(destinationPath):
                    try:
                        os.makedirs(destinationPath)
                    except FileExistsError:
                        pass
                decryptedFilepath = destinationPath

            sevenZipExecutablePath = self.getSevenZipExecutablePath()
            if sevenZipExecutablePath is False:
                self.CELogger.error("Unable to obtain the seven zip executable path")
                return False

            if password is None:
                CMD = [sevenZipExecutablePath, 'x','-r', '-y', file,"-o"+decryptedFilepath]
                executeResult = self.execute(CMD)
            else:
                CMD = [sevenZipExecutablePath, 'x', '-r', '-y', file, '-p',  "-o"+decryptedFilepath]
                stringCMD = f'"{sevenZipExecutablePath}" x -r -y "{file}" -p{password} -o"{decryptedFilepath}"'
                #os.system(stringCMD)
                input = (password + "\r\n").encode("ascii")
                executeResult = self.execute(CMD, input)

            return decryptedFilepath
        except:
            self.CELogger.error(f"A problem occurred while attempting to decrypt the file ({file})")
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self.CELogger.exception(tb)
            return False
```

My compression/Encryption program uses the same approach and execute function and works without problem.

```html
    def sevenZipCompressFileFolder(self, thePath,password=None,destinationDirectory=None,compressionLevel=9,multithreadedCompression="off"):
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(thePath):
                self.CELogger.error(f"Could not compress the file/folder at the path ({thePath}). Does not exist")
                return False
            pathlibPath = pathlib.Path(thePath)
            thePathname = pathlibPath.stem
            if destinationDirectory is None:
                destinationDirectory = str(pathlibPath.parent)
            else:
                if not os.path.exists(destinationDirectory):
                    try:
                        os.makedirs(destinationDirectory)
                    except FileExistsError:
                        pass

            destinationFilepath = os.path.join(destinationDirectory,thePathname+'.7z')
            sevenZipExecutablePath = self.getSevenZipExecutablePath()
            mxEntry = f"-mx={compressionLevel}"
            mmtEntry = f"-mmt={multithreadedCompression}"
            if password is None:
                CMD = [sevenZipExecutablePath, "a", "-t7z", mxEntry, mmtEntry, "-mf=on", "-mhc=on", "-mhe=on", "-ms=on","-m0=LZMA2", "-r", "-y", "-aoa", "-ssw", destinationFilepath, thePath]
                executeResult = self.execute(CMD)
            else:
                CMD = [sevenZipExecutablePath, "a", "-t7z",'-p', mxEntry, mmtEntry, "-mf=on", "-mhc=on", "-mhe=on", "-ms=on","-m0=LZMA2", "-r", "-y", "-aoa", "-ssw", destinationFilepath, thePath]
                input = (password + "\r\n").encode("ascii")
                executeResult = self.execute(CMD, input)
        except:
            self.CELogger.error("An error has occurred while attempting to compress file with seven zip")
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self.CELogger.exception(tb)
            return False
```

The decompression/decryption function works without the password input. However, when supplying the password, it is unable to decrypt it (the password has been verified to be correct). I suspect this is caused by the execute function.

Furthermore, you may notice that I have the os.system call commented out. This is because I have tried using the stringCMD command with the password pre-entered and not passing into the input stream (less secure version). This is also does not work in Python and os.system. However, if I copy the stringCMD variable, and manually open a CMD window, paste, and run, it decrypts it just fine.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried many different things but can't get it to work.

Please note that the errors are isolated to python and these functions. Trivial errors such as unable to overwrite files, wrong password etc. are not a factor and such cases have already been tested.

You may also be interested to note that I am able to decompress and decrypt the file by using the standard 7 zip utility (right click on file and select extract archive, enter password etc.)

Thanks

*EDIT This is also a problem when I try to "update" the compressed archive. Similar to decompression, I need to supply the password. In this situation as well, supplying the password and command through the execute function does not work. 
**So, it appears there is no problem in creating an archive with the password. However, manipulating the file with the same password afterwards is the problem.**